# How to determine the electrolytic capacitor polarity from PCB printings?

Tags: capacitor, pcb, transformer, soldering, polarity

I have this PCB board that I need to solder a capacitor to it.
This is the board:
[image: Solder point on PCB board, half striped half clear circle]

And I'm not sure where should I solder the negative and where the positive.
Can someone please explain what this circle represents on the board?

Comment: I vote for negative to the left (one with lines)

Comment: Have you missed the plus sign (+) on the right side (overlayed with the line)? And without it, the filled area usually means minus/negative (-).

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it out by tracing he connections, it looks like the negative is indeed the one with the lines.

Comment: Another option is to look for another capacitor in the board that is still mounted, if it exists.

Answer (score 3):

Usual Silkscreen identify the shaded side is -ve (GND), also there will be + indication on the other side, looking into your picture it seems the + is merged with the white line

Comment: Bipolar capacitors are quite cheap these days. Use one.